# JavaScripts unexpected value change after parsing to json

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I'm trying generate gantt chart from json string and I have weird problem with parsing Json string to Json object.

i have variable `myString` with json string looking like that:

`{"c": [{"v": "496"}, {"v": "Task name 1"}, {"v": "9, "}, {"v": "Date(2018,6, 19)"}, {"v": "Date(2018, 6, 21)"}, {"v": null}, {"v": 100}, {"v": null}]}`

after using `var jsonData = JSON.parse(myString);` values:`"Date(2018,6, 19)"`and`"Date(2018, 6, 21)"` are changed to: `"Date(2018,7, 19)"` and     `"Date(2018, 7, 21)"`

And i don't know what's wrong with my code.
My full code:

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: URL,
                        data: data,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log(response['chart_data']);

                            var jsonData = JSON.parse(response['chart_data']);
                            console.log(jsonData);
                            var chart_height=jsonData["rows"].length;
                            google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['gantt']});
                            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                            function drawChart() {

                                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

                                var options = {
                                    width: document.getElementById("task_list").offsetWidth,
                                    height:30*chart_height,
                                    gantt: {
                                        trackHeight: 30
                                    }
                                };

                                var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                                chart.draw(data, options);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

SOLUTION:

Thanks to user1531038 new Date() function was executed while parsing, and Date function counts months from 0 to 11.

Comment: Would you please give the result of `console.log(response['chart_data']);`?

Comment: I am not entirely sure but if you are creating `Date` object from Date String from JSON, then this is correct behavior.. since JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. January is 0. December is 11. Try to put date value in console and check.

Comment: You figured out this. As you said Date function counts months from 0 to 11.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine as expected as both `Date(2018,6, 19)` & `Date(2018, 6, 21)` are string **:**

[image]